How do you solve this equation $ \log_{2}(x) = \sqrt x$?
Disclaimer: Guys before voting to get the question closed I strongly feel we should instead have a feature on MSE that can merge such similar/duplicate questions since we got some really cool/through answers on both of them.
Context: Basically was needed in understanding How would you prove $\log_{2}x < \sqrt x$ for $x > 16$?. Please unlock this question and the discussions so I can paste them into this linked question (giving due credit ofc to the authors) so I can then ask my clarifying questions to one of the authors that I was trying to last nigh but those specific questions comments got locked for some reason?
I’m having a hard time solving the equation $\log_{2}(x) = \sqrt x$.
I tried squaring both sides and taking log of both sides, but it’s not really helping.
Kindly please help.

Is $2^{\sqrt x}=x$ easier for you?

There usually isn’t an elementary solution for an equation like this. (The best you can typically do is via the Lambert-W function, but that’s essentially defined as the answer to equations like this.) That said, there is a simple answer here which can be found by guess-and-check.

@J.W.Tanner No not really.

@Semiclassical I can see x = 4, 16 work, but how do I know those are all the solutions?

Finding extrema and monotonicity for function $\log_2 x - \sqrt{x}$ will give you proof, that there are no more solutions.

Incidentally, $\log_2 x$ yields the nicer-looking $\log_2 x$. For future reference! :-)

What are you unable to edit into the question? You should be able to edit the question to include the additional context you want.

As you already wrote in the comments, $x=4$ and $x=16$ are both solutions, so this is just a proof that they are the only solutions.
Let's consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x} - \log_2 x$ function.
Because $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x\ln 2}=\frac{\sqrt{x}\ln 2 - 2 }{2x \ln 2},$$ $f$  has a minimum at $x=\frac{4}{\ln^2 2}\approx 8.325$. From left of minimum on set $\left(0,\frac{4}{\ln^2 2}\right)$ $f$ is strictly decreasing, because there holds $f'(x)<0$, and on set $\left(\frac{4}{\ln^2 2},+\infty \right)$ strictly increasing, because there we have $f'(x)>0$. So, sign of derivative is enough for conclusion about minimum and we do not need second derivative.
On other hand we know $f(4)=f(16)=0$ and as $4<\frac{4}{\ln^2 2}<16$ then on set $(4,16)$ function $f$ is strictly negative and on set $(0,4)\cup(16,+\infty)$ strictly positive.

An alternative sledgehammer route is via the Lambert $W$ function, on both the principal branch $W_0$ and the other real branch $W_{-1}$.
$$
\log_2 x = \sqrt{x}
$$
$$
2\log_2 \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x}
$$
$$
2\frac{\ln \sqrt{x}}{\ln 2} = \sqrt{x}
$$
$$
\ln \sqrt{x} = \left(\frac12 \ln 2\right) \sqrt{x}
$$
$$
\sqrt{x} = e^{\left(\frac12 \ln 2\right) \sqrt{x}}
$$
$$
\sqrt{x} e^{\left(-\frac12 \ln 2\right) \sqrt{x}} = 1
$$
$$
\sqrt{x} e^{\left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right) \sqrt{x}} = 1
$$
$$
\left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right) \sqrt{x} e^{\left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right) \sqrt{x}} = \left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right)
$$
$$
\left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right) \sqrt{x} = W \left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right)
$$
$$
x = \left[ \frac{W \left(\frac12 \ln \frac12\right)}{\frac12 \ln \frac12} \right]^2
$$
(There's probably a faster way to get there, but I'm not the best Lambert manipulator.) Fortunately, we have an identity: When $z \geq 1/e, W_0(z \ln z) = \ln z$, so the principal branch $W(z) = W_0(z)$ gives us
$$
x = \left[ \frac{\ln \frac12}{\frac12 \ln \frac12} \right]^2 = 2^2 = 4
$$
What about the other value? That comes from the other branch, for which there is a corresponding identity: When $0 < z \leq 1/e, W_{-1}(z \ln z) = \ln z$. This would seem difficult to apply to the current equation, since $1/2 > 1/e$. However, note that we have the equality
$$
\frac12 \ln \frac12 = \frac14 \ln \frac14
$$
so we can now also obtain, from $W(z) = W_{-1}(z)$,
$$
x = \left[ \frac{W \left(\frac14 \ln \frac14\right)}{\frac14 \ln \frac14} \right]^2
$$
$$
x = \left[ \frac{\ln \frac14}{\frac14 \ln \frac14} \right]^2 = 4^2 = 16
$$
as desired.

To be sure, there's a certain unsatisfying roundabout-ness to this approach, but it's another way of tackling it.
